# New opened window using selenium doesn't appear in the window handles

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, ie

I need to open a separate window from a link in my main page and leave the main opened.
I am using the following code to do so:

```
self.find_element_by_locator(locator="css==a[href='#/vehicles']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
```

Then I need to do some stuff in the new window, so I try to switch the focus to it:

```
windows = self.driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])
```

Problem:  - The window opens correctly but the focus remains on the main window. (in this case, the Error is that the index is out of range) When I make a Breakpoint and look into the `windows` I see there is only one element in the list, which refers to the main page and the new page doesn't appear. I also tried opening a new Tab (sending keys Control 't' and then sending keys CONTROL TAB) but the problem remains (The window handles only sees one page or tab)

There is a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354850/focus-on-second-page-form-with-selenium) but even the implicit_wait doesn't help.

I saw many people having the same problem, but still can't find an answer.
Do I have to create a completely other WebDriver or is there easier ways to resolve this problem?

I'm working on Windows10 64Bit / Selenium 3.4.3 / Python 3 and IE11 (IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0)

Comment: What about other browsers, does the exact same test pass in other browsers - Chrome, Firefox?

Comment: I can't really say. I need it to run on IE since it's required by the project.

Comment: I am just trying to isolate the issue..trying to see if it is browser-specific.

Comment: Was there any progress with this? I am also sometimes experiencing this. Selenium+Java on IE11 and Chrome. Is it a Selenium issue? Intermittently failing to switch to a new tab or window.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, before switch to the new window, a simply thread sleep make thing done.

```
time.sleep(3)

# switch to new window
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:
Before you switch to a newly open tab, try to wait for a while, e.g.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
```

The number 2 if you're open the second tabs
;3 if you're switching to that third tabs

But I'm not really sure.

Correct me if I'm wronged

Hope it helps